# What do Channel positions mean in Media Info?

Tags: audio, media-player-classic, multi-channel, media-info

I see in MPC-HC Media Info the following information:

```
Channel(s)                     : 6 channels
Channel positions              : Front: L C R, Side: L R, LFE
```

What can it mean?

By sense, "channel positions" should be conversion table from channel number to channel purpose. But why it is separated into two portions "front" and "side"? This separation breaks linear table sense.

Also I can hear, that channels "1" and "2" in my media are left and right, not left and center. Center goes in 3rd place.

So, how to interpret this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the source code, MPC-HC renders the string after parsing the stream, and not by using any kind of numeric IDs. So, those are not necessarily in the same order as you see displayed.

For example, the [AAC channel configuration uses hardcoded strings](https://github.com/mpc-hc/mpc-hc/blob/cf098e587834857916ea77e4a5fa5161352a4132/src/thirdparty/MediaInfo/MediaInfo/Audio/File_Aac_Main.cpp#L177):

```
const char* Aac_ChannelConfiguration[]=
{
    "",
    "Front: C",
    "Front: L R",
    "Front: L C R",
    "Front: L C R, Side: C",
    "Front: L C R, Side: L R",
    "Front: L C R, Side: L R, LFE",
    "Front: L C R, Side: L R, Back: L R, LFE",
```

So, what you're seeing is just the result of a design choice to display the streams in a more "logical" order as you'd hear them.

Bottom line: MPC-HC will only show you what streams are there, not in any particular order.